# Compiling and installing Intel graphics card drivers

Tags: xorg, video, graphics, intel-graphics

I have a laptop which has an Intel core 2 duo processor with in-built graphics card. I have some issues with the video drivers. I want to know from where I can get latest sources code for the drivers, and also need suggestions about the best way of compiling and installing the driver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of compiling the drivers yourself you can just [add this](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa) PPA to your system and update it. All the instructions you need are on the page itself. Follow them carefully, and remember, you do this at your own risk (so the developers are not responsible for breakage).

You can add this PPA to your system using he command `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa`.

It is however strongly recommended to stay with the default drivers that are installed by Ubuntu since they have been widely tested.

If you are looking for something newer but still regarded as stable then look to installing the [x-updates PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
```

Comment: I don't think Ubuntu Tweak is the best way to install the ppa. Unless its status has changed, we should be recommending official methods.

Comment: why is it not the best way to install the ppa? what difference does it make ._.?

Answer (score -1):

You can download the driver from the site of ati or nvidia and install .

Comment: Can you provide more specific information (or at least links) to show how to do that? (Please also provide or link to installation *instructions*, usable once one has downloaded the appropriate driver.)